# Ratio of Hankel functions

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

I am trying to evaluate the ratio 
$\frac{H_m'^{(1)}(z)}{H_m^{(1)}(z)}, m\in N$. $'$ indicates derivative with respect to $z$.
For large $m$, each term in the numerator or denominator can overflow numerically. Is there a convenient way to express the ratio into something manageable? Thanks.

Comment: This [paper](http://faculty.smu.edu/thagstrom/AGH1.pdf) (and references) may help (see $3.2$ and $(3.26)$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni : thank you for the paper. Their equations 3.27 and 3.28 are what I need. For other people's reference, I am copying them here, Let $u_\nu = z H'_m(z)/H_m(z)$,then $u_\nu(z) =\frac{z^2}{\nu-1-u_{\nu-1}(z)} - \nu$. END.

Comment: Glad it helped @user43286. Note that you are encouraged to provide yourself and answer (to close the question). Excellent continuation anyway!